# Use Simplified Mesh for Physics, Then Swap Geometry?

Tags: rigidbody

Is it possible to use a simplified version of my object to bake the physics (rigid body), and then swap out the simple mesh with the more detailed version after the physics has been calculated?

Can you just bake the dynamics and then swap out the simplified object data with the complicated object data?

How that work work, exactly?

Comment: why not just try it out and see what happens? then let us know if you have issues :)

Comment: It's possible, if you bake rigid body physics to keyframes-- you're left with an action, which you can use on any object you want.  But why bother getting rid of the physics object?  Instead, copy transforms via constraint from physics object to rendering object, and disable rendering on the physics object, and you don't have to worry about edits affecting your bakes.